# regex: how to replace all occurrences of a string within another string, if the original string matches some filter

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

- i need to replace all occurrences of a string within another string, if the original string matches some filter
- i can only use a single regex using an `s` command, because i need to send the assembled command to a 3rd party API

i have tried to use positive lookahead as to not consume the string in which i want to replace characters, but somehow i can not get the replacing to work as expected.

here is what i have tried so far and what was the outcome:
(note that the filter - here `[0-9]+` is just an example and will be passed in from the call site and i can not directly influence it.

**expected result:** `9999997890`

`perl -e '$x = "4564567890"; $x =~ s/(?=^[0-9]+$)456/999/g; print $x'`

**actual result:** `9994567890`

1. this replaces only the first occurrence of `456`. why is this happening?
2. even less understandable for me is that if i change the filter lookahead to `(?=.*)`, both occurrences of 456 are being replaced. why does changing the filter have any effect on the replacing portion of the regex?

i seem to be missing some very basic point about how mixing filtering and replacing stuff in one `s` command works.

Comment: I think you need `s/(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+$))\d*?\K456/999/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this seems to work...can you write it as an answer so i can accept  it? also, would you care to explain why your regex works and mine does not? :D

Comment: Probably simpler to understand if you could use eg `^.*?\D.*(*SKIP)(*F)|456` to [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) strings that don't contain only digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only replaces the `456` that is at the start of the string that only consists of digits.

You may use

```
s/(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+$))\d*?\K456/999/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wk18RY/1/)

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+$))` - a custom boundary that matches either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the start of string (`^`) that only contains digits (`(?=\d+$)`)
- `\d*?` - 0+ digits, but as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the currently matched chars
- `456` - a `456` substring.

The idea is:

- Use the `\G` based pattern to pre-validate the string: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=<YOUR_VALID_LINE_FORMAT>$))`
- Then adjust the consuming pattern after the above one.

Comment: You can combine the non-capturing group I think: `s/(?=\G(?!^)|^\d+$)\d*?\K456/999/g`

Comment: @justhalf Yes, that is also working here, just I - personally - do not like using zero-width assertions inside zero-width assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can probably use [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip strings not composed only of digits .

```
s/^\d*\D.*(*SKIP)(*F)|456/999/g
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9RlE2S/2) or [your demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyC1KEdBN1VBXaVCwVZBycTUDIjMLSwNlKwVQEJ1CsX6cTEpWjEueloaWsHengGaGlpumjVAVfqWlpb66dYKBUWZeSVAxer//wMA)

The left part `^\d*\D.*` tries to match any `\D` *non digit*. If found, skips `.*` rest of the string and fails `|` OR matches the specified substring `456`.