# How to perform a RegEx replace only if another a separate filter is matched using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given a string (a path) that matches `/dir1/`, I need to replace all spaces with dashes.

Ex: `/dir1/path with spaces` should become `/dir1/path-with-spaces`.

This could easily be done in 2 steps...

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"^\/dir1\/");
var path = "/dir1/path with spaces";
if (rgx.isMatch(path))
{
    path = (new Regex(@" |\%20")).Replace(path, "-");
}
```

Unfortunately for me, the application is already built with a simple RegEx replace and cannot be modified, so I need to have the RegEx do the work. I thought I had found the answer here:
[regex: how to replace all occurrences of a string within another string, if the original string matches some filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283414/regex-how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-within-another-string-if-the#59283821)

And was able create and test `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\/dir1\/.*$)).*?\K( |\%20)`, but then I learned it does not work in this app because the `\K` is an unrecognized escape sequence (not supported in .NET).

I also tried a positive lookbehind, but I wasn't able to get it to replace all the spaces (only the last if the match was greedy or the first if not greedy). I could put in enough checks to handle the max number of spaces, but as soon as I check for 10 spaces, someone will pass in a path with 11 spaces.

Is there a RegEx only solution for this problem that will work in the .NET engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the unlimited width lookbehind pattern in .NET:

```
Regex.Replace(path, @"(?<=^/dir1/.*?)(?: |%20)", "-")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%2Fdir1%2F.*%3F%29%28%3F%3A%20%7C%2520%29&i=%2Fdir1%2Fpath%20with%20spaces&r=-)

[image]

**Regex details**

- `(?<=^/dir1/.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `/dir1/` and then any zero or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible
- `(?: |%20)` - either a space or `%20` substring.

Comment: That is working perfectly, thank you. I should have been using a .NET tester and I might have stumbled on the solution. However, for my education, why the `?` in the `.*?`? Also, why `(?: |%20)` and not just `( |%20)`?

Comment: @thadmiller `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, since you do not need to value of the group, no need to capture the value. I use `.*?` out of habit, `.*` will work in a similar way here.